Why would query on User, PermissionSet, and PermissionSetAssignment get a secure query included inaccessible field error?
I've been incrementally be updates our managed package code to SF/Apex's new security features.  The query shown below is failing in an installation but running fine in other orgs.  I don't understand out it can throw an inaccessible error.  There is no way to grant access to the standard fields in User, PermissionSet, and PermissionSetAssignments.  I thought all users implicitly have access to those fields.
11:03:11.1 (41147174)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[95]|Aggregations:1|SELECT Id, Email, Name, TimeZoneSidKey, LanguageLocaleKey, (SELECT Id FROM PermissionSetAssignments WHERE PermissionSet.Name = :tmpVar1) FROM User WHERE Id = :tmpVar2 WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
11:03:11.1 (46599928)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
11:03:11.1 (46845712)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
11:03:11.1 (46994213)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
11:03:11.1 (47144235)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
11:03:11.1 (47279623)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
11:03:11.1 (47942885)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
11:03:11.1 (47979478)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[95]|System.QueryException: Insufficient permissions: secure query included inaccessible field


Perhaps one of the many "System Permissions" has to be granted (checked) to be able to read e.g. PermissionSetAssignments?

It turns out the "View Setup and Configuration" permissions is required to read those objects, either from a profile or a permission set.  That's on by default for standard users but was turned off on the profile of the user that had the issue.
